# Append data to linked table without knowing Primary Key of main table

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a Staff Recruitment Database. When all formalities are complete I click a button and basic data is appended to the (recruited) Staff Database .

I also have data for the shift the recruit will work: Hours, Rate of pay etc. This goes into a Linked table.

To append this data I need to know the Primary Key of the recruit. How can I append the data automatically without looking at the table where the basic data is to find the PK?

I'm using INSERT INTO. Staff Database contains the main Staff table and the linked Shifts table.

Comment: What is the Access linked table linked *to*? ...a table in a back-end .accdb (or .mdb) file? ...a SQL Server table? ...something else?

Comment: It's linked to another backend.accdb table.

Comment: Okay, now how are you appending the data to the main table? Are you running an "INSERT INTO..." SQL statement? ...using `Recordset.AddNew`? ...bound form? The "main" table is a local Access table and the "other" table is linked? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16742121/edit) your question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

If the "main" table has an `AutoNumber` field as its Primary Key then immediately after performing the `INSERT INTO` statement you can use some code like this to retrieve the PK value you just inserted:

```
Dim rst AS DAO.Recordset, newPK as Long
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY", dbOpenSnapshot)
newPK = rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

You can then use the `newPK` value as a foreign key in the related tables.

### Edit re: using the new value

Based on the code sample in your comment, try this instead:

```
strSQL = _
        "INSERT INTO tblShifts (StartDt, [To], Hours, StaffLookup) " & _
        "IN ""C:\__tmp\Staff.accdb"" " & _
        "SELECT qryAdd.DateStarted, qryAdd.To, qryAdd.Hours, " & newPK & " AS StaffLookup FROM qryAdd"
```

If [tblShifts] really *is* a linked table then you shouldn't need to use the `IN (mydatabase)` clause because a linked table will behave just like a local table in this case. Note the corrections to the syntax as well, especially the bracketing of `[To]` which is a reserved word in Access.

Comment: My INSERT INTO statement includes the line:

Comment: My INSERT INTO statement (part):
    "INSERT INTO tblShifts StartDt, To, Hours, StaffLookup" & _
    "IN (mydatabase) " & _
    "SELECT qryAdd.DateStarted,qryAdd.To, qruAdd.Hours, newPK "

This doesn't work. How can I use newPK? I guess I could put it in a new table but that sounds rather "Heath-Robinson".

Comment: Sorry - I've misled you. I'm working from database "Recruitment" and inserting into database "Staff". Database staff has tables "Staff" and "Shifts". Shifts has a lookup to the PK in Staff. So from database recruitment I need the PK in Staff so I can append data to Shifts.

Comment: @user2204315 Oh, I see (I think...). You'll probably save yourself some headaches by just creating table links in "Recruitment" for the tables that you will be manipulating in "Staff" and then work with those (linked) tables just as if they were local ones.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have got a solution. I can retrieve the PK into the recruitment db like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblCBSStaffLookup ( StaffLookupCBS, NINO ) " & _
             "SELECT tblStaff.ID, tblStaff.NINO " & _
             "FROM tblStaff IN 'C:\Users\Peter.Home-PC\Documents\NEMS\Databases\Frontends\Staff.accdb' " & _
             "WHERE (((tblStaff.NINO)=[Forms]![frmSuccess]![NINO])) "
```

tblCBSStaffLookup is a table I have now made in the recruitment db to collect the PK and NINO.
WHERE matches the newly arrived NINO to a form in the recruitment db which already has the NINO. I have set up constraints to make sure that NINO's are valid. I have also set up a query in the recruitment db to retrive all NINO's from the main db, so that new recruits don't get added the the main db twice.

Comment: Note for future readers: [NINO (National Insurance Number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_insurance_number) is the U.K version of a U.S. "Social Security Number" or a Canadian "Social Insurance Number" (government-created ID number for an individual).